# Como eu conto a quantidade de produtos por categoria?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a tabela `tbl_produtos`

- id_produto
- nome_produto
- cat_produto

Tenho a tabela `tbl_categorias`

- id_categoria
- nome_categoria

Como eu contaria a quantidade de produtos para uma determinada ***categoria***, por exemplo `Cartazes`, que é a `000001` através de uma ***SQL***?

> **Atualização**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `cat_produto` em `tbl_produtos` é o nome ou o ID da categoria?

Comment: Fera `cat_produto` é o id da categoria dentro de `tbl_produtos` !!!

Comment: O código `000001` é `char` ou `int`?

Comment: O código `000001` é `int`.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius você pode fazer como na minha resposta, uma subquery, a query retornará a mesma coisa que já retorna hoje em sua aplicação mas com um campo virtual "quantidade" que foi adicionado de acordo com a quantidade de produtos em cada categoria.

Comment: Fiz duas melhorias, agora são listadas as categorias que não possuem produtos e adicionei a ordenação pelos nomes das categorias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma solução com boa performance e legibilidade pode ser obtida com o uso de [count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) e [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
SELECT
    c.id_categoria,
    c.nome_categoria,
    count(p.id_produto) AS quantidade
FROM
    tbl_categorias c
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_produtos p ON p.cat_produto = c.id_categoria
GROUP BY
    c.id_categoria,
    c.nome_categoria
ORDER BY
    c.nome_categoria;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar uma subQuerie para isso, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
SELECT (
   SELECT count(id) FROM produtos WHERE categoria_id = categorias.id
) as quantidade
FROM categorias WHERE [sua condição para categoria]
```

no seu caso você pode fazer

```
SELECT id_categoria,
       nome_categoria,
       (SELECT count(id_produto) 
        FROM tbl_produtos WHERE cat_produto=tbl_categorias.id_categoria
       ) as quantidade
    FROM tbl_categorias
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--=============================================================-->
<!--===Inicio - Essa Parte trata a quantidade por Categoria======-->

    <?php
    $categoria = array(); //Declarado um Array sem Tamanho
    $contitensCat = 0;    //Essa Variavel vai contar quantas categorias tem Geral
    $itensCat = 0;        //Essa vai entrar na function e contar a quantidade de cada categoria de quem esta chamando a function

            $buscaSegura = $pdo->prepare("SELECT categoria FROM produtos"); //Faz a Busca da coluna inteira da Categoria do banco de dados
            $buscaSegura->execute(); // Executa o Select
            $consultaBanco = $buscaSegura->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($consultaBanco as $consulta) 
    {
        array_push($categoria, $consulta['categoria']);
        $contitensCat++; //A cada linha Encontrada essa variavel vai ser incrementada
    }


function cont($palavra,$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $contitensCat; $i++)
    {
        if($categoria[$i]==$palavra)//Se achar a palavra, ai entra nesse IF
        {
            $itensCat++;
        }
    }
    return $itensCat;//Retorna  Quantidade de itens achado de acordo com o parâmetro passado a função
}
    ?>

<!--======Fim - Essa Parte trata a quantidade por Categoria======-->
<!--=============================================================-->

 - Acessórios (<?=cont("ac",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
 - Brinquedos  (<?=cont("brinq",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
 - Games (<?=cont("games",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
 - Informática (<?=cont("inf",$categoria,$contitensCat,$itensCat);?>)
```